# How do you disable Roslyn Analyzers when using msbuild through the command line?

Tags: msbuild, fxcop, roslyn-code-analysis

The Roslyn Analyzers are installed as nuget packages, which are dependencies of the FxCop Analyzers (also installed as nuget packages).

I have enabled full solution analysis as instructed here: [How to Enable and disable full solution analysis for managed code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/how-to-enable-and-disable-full-solution-analysis-for-managed-code?view=vs-2019).

I have a fairly large solution with most of the projects using the FxCop/Roslyn Analyzers and Visual Studio builds fine, usually in under a minute.

However, when running msbuild through the command line using:

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/MSBuild/15.0/Bin/MSBuild.exe" "C:\Source\MySolution\MySmartClient.sln" /p:Configuration=Develop;Platform="Any CPU" /
t:Build
```

Building the solution takes anywhere from 4-15 minutes. The same is true on the build server which uses the same command.

I've tried `/p:RunCodeAnalysis=False` and that has no effect. I've also used process monitor to emulate the msbuild command that VS sends to msbuild with no change.

And, according to this doc: [How to: Enable and disable automatic code analysis for managed code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/how-to-enable-and-disable-automatic-code-analysis-for-managed-code?view=vs-2019)

> The Enable Code Analysis on Build check box only affects static code analysis. It doesn't affect Roslyn code analyzers, which always execute at build if you installed them as a NuGet package.

These excessive build times are not practical. Is there any way to disable when using msbuild through the command line?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57144221/736079

Answer (score 10):

It's not really supported, but there is a workaround:

Create a `Directory.Build.targets` (msbuild >= v15.0), `After.{SolutionName}.sln.targets` (msbuild < 15.0) file in your solution root folder and add:

```
<Project>
  <Target Name="DisableAnalyzers" 
           BeforeTargets="CoreCompile" 
           Condition="'$(UseRoslynAnalyzers)' == 'false'"> 
    <!-- 
       Disable analyzers via an MSBuild property settable on the command line. 
    --> 
    <ItemGroup> 
      <Analyzer Remove="@(Analyzer)" /> 
    </ItemGroup> 
  </Target> 
</Project>
```

You can pass in `/p:UseRoslynAnalyzers=false` now to remove all analyzers configured in the project.

See also:

- https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/23591#issuecomment-507802134
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets

You can edit the condition to also trigger on `RunCodeAnalysis=False` or `Never`.

```
<Target Name="DisableAnalyzers" 
        BeforeTargets="CoreCompile" 
        Condition="
           '$(UseRoslynAnalyzers)' == 'false' 
           or '$(RunCodeAnalysis)' == 'false' 
           or '$(RunCodeAnalysis)' == 'never'" >
```

To disable a specific analyzer, use this trick:

> We just spent 2 hours figuring out how to disable an analyzer based on an MSBuild property, AMA.
>
> https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1173996405276467202?s=09

[image]

Comment: I didn't have any luck getting the Directory.Build.targets method working but was successful in adding the target to .csproj file.

Comment: Creating a vDirectory.Build.targets file was the only thing that worked for me on our build server, using msbuild from vs 2019 and a net48 project including a netstandard 2.0 library. I've spent days on this!

Answer (score 8):

The documentation has changed since the original answers. There is now [this page documenting how to disable code analysis from analyzers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/disable-code-analysis?view=vs-2019):

There are 3 MSBuild properties you can use to control analyzer behavior (all default to true):

- **RunAnalyzersDuringBuild** Controls whether analyzers run at build time.
- **RunAnalyzersDuringLiveAnalysis** Controls whether analyzers analyze code live at design time.
- **RunAnalyzers** Disables analyzers at both build and design time. This property takes precedence over RunAnalyzersDuringBuild and RunAnalyzersDuringLiveAnalysis.

Edit: it looks like there is [an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/40926) being tracked where these props don't work unless your project has Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.targets included. So your mileage may vary until this is fixed.

Answer (score 4):

**In case anyone else happens to find themselves here, I came across this issue on the dotnet/roslyn project on Github:**

[Feature: MSBuild switch for turning on/off analysis #23591](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/23591)

The preceding issue describes a work-around:

[Substitute for old MSBuild properties? #1431](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/1431)

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <RunCodeAnalysis Condition="'$(RunCodeAnalysis)' == ''">true</RunCodeAnalysis>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="<whatever analyzers package you are depending on>" Condition="'$(RunCodeAnalysis)' == 'true'" />
</ItemGroup>
```

```
# You'll need to run a restore when changing this value
msbuild /p:RunCodeAnalysis=false
```

Although, I had a couple of differences though since I'm not using package references. This worked for me.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Analyzer Include="<whatever analyzers package you are depending on>" Condition="'$(RunCodeAnalysis)' == 'true'" />
</ItemGroup>

<!-- I added the condition to the EnsureNugetPackageBuildImports too. -->
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="'$(RunCodeAnalysis)' == 'true' AND !Exists('<relative path to the prop of whatever analyzers you are depending on>')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '<relative path to the prop of whatever analyzers you are depending on>'))" />
</Target>
```